# Name That Song!

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, music

A homeless man and a rich billionaire are discussing music.

The rich person exclaims suddenly "OK, if you can name a song that includes my daughter's name, I will give you one million dollars. Her name is Cassiopeia Lucria Dante."

The homeless man gives her the name of the song he finds and becomes $1,000,000 richer.

What was his answer?

Comment: Isn't that the hit song, "She Walks Like Cassiopeia Lucria Dante" by One Direction, or something? Or did I hear it wrong?

Comment: @Xenocacia i'll +1 if you write that as an answer :P

Comment: hmm... I was thinking the same exact thing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the answer is

> happy birthday Cassiopeia Lucria Dante - birthday song

Answer (score 1):

The homeless man asks to borrow the rich man's cell phone, and proceeds to record himself singing a short, improvised tune. Then, he uploads it to a music streaming site, hands the phone back to the rich man, and says

> Here's a song with the title you were looking for.

The title of the song he uploaded? "Cassiopeia Lucria Dante." It's self-published, but certainly a song.